# Custom Exceptions in Web API

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

Can someone help me in creating an exception which has the overridden message, source and stack trace values.

I tried using httperror in the HttpResponseMessage, but I need to add Stacktrace and Source to the response exception also. Here's my code:

```
public Product GetProductById(int id)
{
    var product = products.FirstOrDefault((p) => p.Id == id);
    HttpResponseMessage errorResponse = null;

        if (product == null)
        {
            //using httperror
            var message = String.Format("Customer with id: {0} was not found", id);
            var httpError = new HttpError(message);
            errorResponse = Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, httpError);
            throw new HttpResponseException(errorResponse);
        }

    return product;
}
```

Output: `{ Message: "Customer with id: 7 was not found" }`

Comment: That might be by design.. The user should never be able to see a stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the [HttpConfiguration.IncludeErrorDetailPolicy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.httpconfiguration.includeerrordetailpolicy%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) property?

Comment: Thank you, I solved customizing httperror  HttpError myCustomError = new HttpError("My custom error message") { { "CustomErrorCode", exp.Source }, { "Stacktrace", exp.StackTrace } };
                throw new HttpResponseException(Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, myCustomError));